# Groovy: Why can't the closure access itself?

Tags: groovy

I'm a Groovy newbie. When I run the following script Groovy reports "No such property: tailFactorial for class ***". Shouldn't the closure access the local variable tailFactorial?

```
def factorial(int factorialFor) {
    def tailFactorial = { int number, BigInteger theFactorial = 1 ->
        number == 1 ? theFactorial :
        tailFactorial.trampoline(number - 1, number * theFactorial)
    }.trampoline()
    tailFactorial(factorialFor)
}
println "factorial of 5 is ${factorial(5)}"
println "Number of bits in the result is ${factorial(5000).bitCount()}"
```

What makes me confused is that If I change the above code to the following one:

```
def factorial(int factorialFor) {
    def tailFactorial
    tailFactorial = { int number, BigInteger theFactorial = 1 ->
        number == 1 ? theFactorial :
        tailFactorial.trampoline(number - 1, number * theFactorial)
    }.trampoline()
    tailFactorial(factorialFor)
}
println "factorial of 5 is ${factorial(5)}"
println "Number of bits in the result is ${factorial(5000).bitCount()}"
```

It runs well.

We can find that the only difference between the two pieces of code is that in the first one we declare and define the closure at the same time but in the second one we declare the closure without definition. The definition goes in a separated line.

How could this happen? I'm using Groovy 2.4.3 and Java 7 and look forward to your help. Thanks.

Comment: Simply because in your first code snippet the `tailFactorial` closure doesn't exist yet since it's being executed, so it cannot be access from within itself.

Comment: Val is correct, in the 4th line of code, you reference tailFactorial during the initializer for the tailFactorial closure variable.  Since initializers are executed prior to the declaration completing, the tailFactorial variable doesn't exist yet, and can't be referenced.  In the 2nd example, the variable is created first, without initialization, so it can be referenced in the assignment closure.

Comment: @BillJames, I think the closure declaration is OK because the code of the closure will not be executed when the initialization executes. Like [Can't call method itself in grails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6122626/cant-call-method-itself-in-grails) said, it's a trick. I just don't know how this trick works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can not access the variable, to which the closure will be assigned to, since it pops into existence *after* the right hand side (or at least get's not captured).

This is the reason, why the second example (the same code like in the groovy docs) works.  The variable is already declared and the closure can capture it by this name. (remember, that the closure code it not executed at once - at this exact point in time `tailFactorial` would be null).

But since you are only interested in the trampoline call on the closure, you can simply call it on the closure itself.  `trampoline` is a method of `Closure`:

```
def factorial(int factorialFor) {
    def tailFactorial = { int number, BigInteger theFactorial = 1 ->
        number == 1 ? theFactorial :
        // XXX
        trampoline(number - 1, number * theFactorial)
    }.trampoline()
    tailFactorial(factorialFor)
}
println "factorial of 5 is ${factorial(5)}"
println "Number of bits in the result is ${factorial(5000).bitCount()}"
```

Comment: your solution really works but I still want to know why the second code snippet works. Thanks.

Comment: @SamuelGong i have added a better(?) explanation about the capturing part

Comment: I think you're right. By the way, the Groovy closure works differently from JavaScript. For example, the following code works well: var factorial = function(n) {
    if (n == 1) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return n * factorial(n - 1);
    }
} 
alert(factorial(5));

Comment: My final understanding is that the local variables should be existent before a closure is declared so that the closure can capture them then use them. Am I correct, @cfrick?

Comment: at first glance i can not find in the docs a clear statement, that says this. but to my knowledge, groovy clojures captures vars "above" itself and not the LHS in an assignment of itself. yes, you are correct.